# Why is this snippet giving 6 as output?

Tags: c

```
 int main(){    
       char s[1000];    
       s[0]='Q';    
       printf("%d",strlen(s));    
       return 0;    
    }
```

The above code is giving 6 as output.
The output should be 1 in this case.

```
int main(){    
       char s[1000];     
       printf("%d",strlen(s));    
       return 0;    
}
```

This code was even giving 6 as output.
where it should be 1000 or 0 or some garbage value.
I have tried it in **" hackerrank "**, but it was giving 6 as the length.
When the same code was tried in TURBOC it was giving the correct answer.
I was unable to find the reason for this output. Can someone please sort it out and give the exact solution to this problem.

Comment: did you append `\0` to end of string?

Comment: You should look up the docs for strlen().  man strlen.

Comment: '6' IS a garbage value:)

Answer (score 3):

Local non-static variables, like your array, will not be initialized. Its value or contents will be *indeterminate*.

That means the likelihood of your array containing a string terminator where you want it to be is close to zero.

Passing your array without initialization to a string-function leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to explicitly initialize your array, like e.g.

```
char s[1000] = "";
```

Comment: You could also use `char s[1000] = {0};` to fill it with `'\0'`s.

Comment: @InternetAussie My initialization is equivalent to yours.

Comment: Oh, true. Oops. Still an alternative :p

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
char s[1000];
```

declares an array of 1000 chars but it doesn't put anything in it. Because it is a local variable, it is allocated on the stack and, apart from reserving the necessary space to hold 1000 `char`s, the compiler doesn't generate any code to set their content (to zero or something else).

All 1000 values are garbage. It just happens that the 7<sup>th</sup> of them is zero. `strlen()` stops counting when it reaches it and returns `6` but this value is also garbage. It could be `230790345` or something else as well. It could also produce an infinite loop, a segmentation fault or make you spit fire like a dragon. Anything is possible and permitted by the language in this situation. It is called [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).